# Android app crash after open other apps

Tags: android, android-activity, crash

I have a problem with my app. The app works perfectly. If I press the back button the app obviously closes without any problems. If I press the home button the app is in the background. If I open the app immediately this works, but if I open other apps and then I open my app often crashes.

How can I fix? I have to implement the method onPause? But how?

```
26 21:46:27.341  29621-29621/parlamento_italiano.android E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: parlamento_italiano.android, PID: 29621
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{parlamento_italiano.android/com.prova.prova3.Quarta}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3218)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1000(ActivityThread.java:198)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1676)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
 Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:138)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:334)
        at com.prova.prova3.R2.onCreateView(R2.java:77)
        at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1026)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1207)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1189)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2001)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:165)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:507)
        at com.prova.prova3.Quarta.onStart(Quarta.java:291)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1250)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6538)
```

This cause the crash

```
        int x = Integer.parseInt(numVoti.replaceAll("[\\D]", ""));
```

Comment: @DomenicoRafti Good you've identified the line causing the crash - now why are you doing that line such that you are trying to parse a string with no number.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your app does not go in the background, when you press the Home button. It just gets added in the [Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html). Second, try to explain to us the resources your app uses, how they interact with other apps, possibly.

Comment: My app does not interact with other apps.

Comment: I mean the resources you use in your app.

Comment: What is `numVoti` ? Try giving us some hints on what your code does. We people try to help you out, so you try too.